# How to add associations in Model dynamically in extjs

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I want to add the associations on model based on the value of a field.
For example:

I want to add associations like

Parent Model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.parentModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [
        'App.model.ChildModel1',
        'App.model.ChildModel2',
    ],
    idProperty: 'type',
    fields: [
        'name',
        'type'
    ],
proxy:[//proxy]
});
```

I want to add associations like

```
hasMany:{
model:'App.model.ChildModel1' 
}
```

if my value for 'type' field is automobile.

Else I want to add associations like

```
hasMany:{
model:'App.model.ChildModel2' 
}
```

How can I check this on fly and add associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches come to my mind.

The first thing you can try is use the model's `setFields()` method.  I have never used this method before, but according to the docs it looks like it could satisfy what you are looking for.  An example can be found here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189160-Ext.data.Model-setFields-not-Working-as-Expected

--OR--

Something I have done in the past is create 2 stores that use `'App.model.ChildModel1'` and the other uses `'App.model.ChildModel2'`.  Then you can use `reconfigure()` on the panel/grid and give it the store appropriately.